# Facing issue during update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have stored a value in a variable in shell. like below

```
app=$(mysql -uroot -p123456 -e 'SELECT applicant FROM `leave` where status="Applied" and applying_date= curdate()' comviva|tail -1);
```

but using this variable if i want to update any column i am facing a error. below is the error.
Update Command:

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -e "update leave set status=\"pending\" where applicant=\"$app\"" comviva;
```

The error encountered:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave set status="pending" where applicant="a"' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Error was due to use of a [*Reserved Word*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-5.6.19), `LEAVE` in the statement, as an identifier.

So to use it as an identifier in your statement, use back ticks around it.

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -e "update `leave` set status='pending' where applicant='$app'" comviva;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -e "update leave set status='pending' where applicant='$app'" comviva;
```